# Selenium Webdriver sendkeys: clears down fields after text is entered

Tags: selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I'm encountering a particularly frustrating issue with Webdriver's SendKeys method.  I am witnessing the fields being filled, but as soon as focus is removed, the fields get cleared.

Source code snippet:

```
    <div class="search-row__departure">
<div class="search-label">
<label onclick="$(this).parent().parent().find('.airport-input-row:first input, select').focus();">Departure</label>
</div>
<div class="search-input__text">
<span id="id23">
<span id="idc">
<div class="airport-input-row">
    <span class="inputContainer">
    <input id="id11" class="departurePoint" name="airport_selection_panel:departurePoint:departureAirportPanel:listView:0:selector:airportFragment:departurePoint" value="" autocomplete="off" onblur="var wcall=wicketAjaxPost('./?0-IBehaviorListener.4-brix~page~2-brix~journey~4-brix~package_search-child-child-packages_search_form-airport_selection_panel-departurePoint-departureAirportPanel-listView-0-selector-airportFragment-departurePoint', wicketSerialize(Wicket.$('id11')),function() { }.bind(this),function() { }.bind(this), function() {return Wicket.$('id11') != null;}.bind(this));" type="text"/>
</span>
<script>$(function(){$('#idc').parent().trigger('addField',['departurePoint','#idc .departurePoint']);})</script>
</div>
```

Notice the input tag has many attributes.

I have tried:

```
inputField.clear();
inputField.click();
inputField.sendKeys("text to input");
```

also:

```
String script = "arguments[0].value='text to input';";
javaScriptExecutor("script here", inputField);
```

also:

```
inputField.sendKeys("text to input", Keys.TAB);
```

In all instances, the field is filled and then erased as the driver moves to the next field. No difference on FF or Chrome

I am using Selenium 3.0.0-beta3, Firefox 49.0, Chrome 53.

Comment: Like you said:

**Notice the input tag has many attributes.**

Mind to check that there is no need to select smthn after entering data? Could it be that field clears because no corresponding data is found?

Comment: There is an onBlur function which seems to be an ajax call. You need to check what it does.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using the beta version? 2.53.0 is tried and tested. Could be a bug in the beta version.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this issue is not relevant for you anymore.
Nevertheless, I have a kind of workaround, which I implemented to handle a similar case in automated tests on Selenium C#.

I've just added `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))` prior to `webElement.SendKeys('text')` execution.
It seems that in my case some of the JS scripts were still working on text sending, because it was the first action on the page in scope of the test execution.
I've tried to use webDriver wait with Selenium JsScriptExecutor in such way to wait until JS scripts will stop their execution but it seems not working in my case:

```
new WebDriverWait(this.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout))
                .Until((Driver)
                => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)this.Driver)
                .ExecuteScript("return document.readyState")
                .ToString()
                .Equals("complete"));
```

So that, the timeout  became not the best, but still working decision.